# Python: Function doesn´t return any value

Tags: python-3.x

I need to call the `attack()` or `checkLife()` functions but those do not return any values. What can I do to fix this?

```
class Enemy: life = 100


    def choose(self,ch):
        return {1:self.attack,
                2:self.checkLife
                }[ch]


    def attack(self):
        print('ouch!')
        self.life-=1

    def checkLife(self):
        if(self.life <= 0):
            print('I am dead')
        else:
            print(str(self.life) + "Life Left...")

enemy1 = Enemy()
enemy1.choose(1)
```

Comment: If course it doesn't return you anything because you don't return anything

Comment: Hi Hussein, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this so that others can help you more easily: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add the parenthesis `()`

```
class Enemy: 
  life = 100
  def choose(self,ch):
    return {1:self.attack(), #here
            2:self.checkLife() #and here
            }[ch]


  def attack(self):
    print('ouch!')
    self.life-=1

  def checkLife(self):
    if(self.life <= 0):
        print('I am dead')
    else:
        print(str(self.life) + "Life Left...")

enemy1 = Enemy()
enemy1.choose(1)
```